# ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expectedA

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-boot, plsql

I am learning SQL and Java Spring Boot.

I have created an SQL statements manager in my program and used it in my java files. Below is the SQL statement.

`mapSQLStmt.put("valcurpcustomer", "select * from acnts left join clients on acnts.acnts_client_num = clients.clients_code where acnts.acnts_internal_acnum = '?' and clients.clients_type_flg='C' ");`

and down below is how I pass `acnts.acnts_internal_acnum` into a statement.

```java
revalDTO.clearMap();
revalDTO.setValue("SQLToken","valcurpcustomer");
revalDTO.setValue("Args",corpcust.trim());
revalDTO.setValue("DataTypes","S");
revalDTO = qrymgr.getInfo(revalDTO);
if(revalDTO.getValue("Result").equalsIgnoreCase("RowPresent")) {

}
else if (revalDTO.getValue("Result").equalsIgnoreCase("RowNotPresent")) {
    revalDTO.setValue(ErrorKey, "Only Corporate Customer ... ");
    merrmsg = "MF:txtCustomerCode|"+revalDTO.getValue(ErrorKey).toString();
    return false;
}
```

`qrymgr` is the query manager

But even though I am passing the existing field in DB I am getting this error.

Please educate me or point me in a direction where I can learn.

I apologize for my English, I am using a translator.

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around your bind variable placeholder (i.e. it should be `?` not `'?'`), but that won't cause the error you're seeing. Are you able to see the actual SQL statement issued to the database - maybe it's in a log file somewhere?

Comment: On a side note: You will never get any outer joined rows with your left outer join, because you are dismissing them in your where clause right away. (If an acnts row has no clients match, then the client columns will be null in the joined row, so the clients_type_flg will not equal 'C'.)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I want result == 0 records from the right side, if there is no match. is the query not efficient?

Comment: It seems you haven't understood my explanation. When there is an acnts row that has no match in clients, `from acnts left join clients on ...` creats a result row with all clients columns set to null. Then you have `where ... clients.clients_type_flg = 'C'`. As the clients_type_flg is null in that outer-joined row, the row will get dismissed. Move that condition to the `ON` clause, so as to say "outer join all clients_type_flg-C client rows to the acnts rows.

Comment: BTW: Hasn't Tim's answer solved your original problem? You said you were getting ORA-00923 with your query. Has Tim's answer solved that issue for you? Then you should mark it as accepted (with the tick/check next to the answer). If you are still getting this error, then you should tell us so.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner `select * from acnts
outer join clients on
clients.clients_type_flg = 'C' and acnts_client_num = clients.clients_code` you mean to rearrange like this? I have tried to compare both cases and result returned  is the same.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner No Tim's answer did not solve the problem, that is not the cause of the error

Comment: The error message "ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected" indicates a syntax error, but the query you are showing has no syntax error (see https://dbfiddle.uk/VJtFYLqo). This means the SQL gets mutilated on its way to the DBMS. Maybe some Java person can explain this. Maybe they will need to see more code, though.

Comment: And yes, I meant to rearrange the `ON` clause like this. (Except that `outer join` is syntactically wrong; it must be `left outer join` or `left join`.) So, there are actually two problems: In Oracle the query runs, but you don't get the expected output. And from Java you get a syntax error. This request asks for the problem in Java. Maybe you should open another request for the problem in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

The only obvious problem with your SQL statement is that you have put single quotes around the `?` placeholder.  Try using this version:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM acnts a
LEFT JOIN clients c ON a.acnts_client_num = c.clients_code
WHERE a.acnts_internal_acnum = ? AND  -- Note: NO single quotes around ?
      c.clients_type_flg = 'C'
```